# Dealing with parental alienation syndrome (PAS) when the child is younger

Tags: toddler, pre-schooler, parents, divorce

Similar to [this question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/3442/how-to-go-about-regaining-the-trust-of-my-child), except it just started yesterday, and the child is 3.

---

My son is 3, turning 4 next month. My ex was inching to take away my weekend visits, and I compromised (since it's summer). She then tried taking away my one weeknight from visitation, and I said no. She turned hostile towards me, and I did my best to ignore it.

She promised to take him fishing on my week day without first checking with me. After I said that I had plans with him on that day (during my time that the consent order we have in place says), she told me that **I** had to tell him that **I'm** cancelling his plans to go fishing. And yes, after researching about PAS, I know that's a classic start.

After I picked him up, he seemed normal. I always say "I love you" when I buckle him in before driving *anywhere*, even down the street. After we got home, he said he wanted to go back to his mom's, repeatedly. I asked why, and he said "Because  and mommy said so". He still listened like he normally does, but this behaviour only started when I denied her request to take away all my time with him.

This morning, before I went to drop him off, he was back to normal: said "I love you" to me, cuddled with me before leaving, etc. I felt a bit better, but I still feel extremely powerless in dealing with this issue.

In my province, there is no law against a parent alienating the other parent to the child. Custody would not be granted on this basis alone. According to many experts, I should just leave it alone, and always tell him that I love him, and never bash his mom and step dad (which I never do anyways; I've heard too many stories of messed up minds in teens who believed this nonsense was about them). So my question is, with such a young child, **what can I do to rectify the issue, and make sure he always knows I love him, no matter what anyone else says?**

---

(I'm sorta new to this particular SE; if I tagged wrong, please fix)

Comment: I feel this link is useful to add to this question as well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parental_alienation_syndrome

Comment: @Erik I read the entire paper that most of that Wiki page was written about last night. It was quite a good read!

Comment: @CanadianLuke The Wiki page also goes on to describe the scientific status of PAS as "critiqued as lacking a scientific basis, and as a hypothesis whose proponents have failed to meet the scientific burden of proof to merit acceptance". In scientific terms, people being jerks is not a "syndrome".

Comment: @atsby I agree, but that's the name of it

Comment: +1 this sounds like a really rough issue, and it's good you are working to examine it from all angles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> She promised to take him fishing on my week day without first checking with me. After I said that I had plans with him on that day (during my time that the consent order we have in place says), she told me that I had to tell him that I'm cancelling his plans to go fishing. And yes, after researching about PAS, I know that's a classic start.

Optimal play here would've been to say you think going fishing is a great idea and suggest that the three of you all go together. Then the ball would then be in the mother's court to cancel the plans to go fishing.

> This morning, before I went to drop him off, he was back to normal: said "I love you" to me, cuddled with me before leaving, etc. I felt a bit better, but I still feel extremely powerless in dealing with this issue.

Well, regardless what the mother might be telling him or not, you have to realize it's a pretty new experience for the kid to be with just one parent. Also, the dynamic when there's only one adult with a child can be quite stilted. Do you have a new S.O. in your life? If not, maybe you should start dating.

> what can I do to rectify the issue, and make sure he always knows I love him, no matter what anyone else says?

I'd suggest focusing less on the "I love you"s and more on being a fun dad who's moved on from his ex.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned we've been broken up for 3 years now, the consent order in place for that long

Comment: +1 very touchy issue, but I do like the game theory approach in this answer.